# What is the dual norm of Mahalanobis norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces

What is the dual norm of Mahalanobis norm?
$||x||_M = \sqrt{x^TMx}$ where $M$ is positive definite.
here are the definitions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dual norm of $||x||_M$ is $||x||_{M^{-1}}$.

Letting $M$ be the Identity matrix yields the well known special case that the dual of the Euclidean norm is the Euclidean norm.

The proof is left as an exercise for the reader.